# Take the names from a condition on another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data set similar to this:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | Q3 2022 |
| Name1 | Q2 2022 |
| Name2 | Q2 2022 |
| Name3 | Q2 2022 |

so I want all the names that in Q2 2022 and has no occurrences in other dates, for example I want Q2 2022 I should receive Name2 and Name3

Comment: Please use the formatted text for your data instead of an image, see [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you can just use `drop_duplicates` to remove multiple mentions of `Name`.

```
# Create some dummy data
d = {'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd'], 'year': [2022, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2020]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df


name    year
0   a   2022
1   b   2022
2   c   2022
3   b   2021
4   d   2020
```

From there you can just remove all the duplicate rows and then just select the year.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep=False)
df.loc[df['year']==2022]


name    year
0   a   2022
2   c   2022
```

So if you want a list of the values of `name` you could just do:

```
df.loc[df['year']==2022, 'name'].to_list() # --> ['a', 'c']
```

Comment: No not exactly, I have duplicated names that's fine I don't want to remove them I just want to Print the names that occurred in specific date and didn't occurs on another date

Comment: You wouldn't need to remove them from the original DataFrame. You just wouldn't replace `df`.  It is just a way to get a list of names that uniquely exist for a specific date.